# Excel 2010 VBA 7.0: String Length Limitation in VBA Watch Window

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running VBA sub that builds a string by adding substrings to the beginning and end of the 'master' string. But when the string variable pases 250 characters the Watch Window only displays the first 250 characters.

The resulting string is correct if I look at it in the Immediate Window by using Debug.Print for example.

Is there a flag somewhere that I can set to allow the Watch Window to display more characters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything on **MSDN** websites but it [appears to be](http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VOK159/YD112450551.htm),

`The Watch Window does not show more than 256 class objects in a collection !!!`

There is no way to adjust the `Watch variable size` beyond that!

I would suggest using `Debug.Print` and `Immediate Window`

Comment: Thanks for that reference.  So for a string is each character then considered an object?  Sorry for the basic question but I'm not clear on how 251 characters in a string variable is more than 256 class objects.  Thanks again.